# Custom function that replaces values in a vector in R

Tags: r, function, replace

I have this code:

```
val_hps_mix <- 0
co_neg_HP <- 1
co_pos_HP <- 2
e <- c(.1, -.2, 0, -.2)
if(val_hps_mix == 0 & co_neg_HP > 0 & co_pos_HP > 0) e[e < max(e[e < 0])] <- 0
if(val_hps_mix == 0 & co_neg_HP > 0 & co_pos_HP > 0) e[e < 0] <- e[e < 0]/length(e[e < 0])
e
```

As expected, this returns:

```
[1]  0.1 -0.1  0.0 -0.1
```

How can I put the IFs into a function? This below does not work, I do not obtain the expected result..

```
    C.NAcc_hetero <- function(){
    if(val_hps_mix == 0 & co_neg_HP > 0 & co_pos_HP > 0) e[e < max(e[e < 0])] <- 0
    if(val_hps_mix == 0 & co_neg_HP > 0 & co_pos_HP > 0) e[e < 0] <- e[e < 0]/length(e[e < 0])
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. As you can see, there are not default arguments, so you can change and set everything as you need/want.

```
C.NAcc_hetero <- function(e, val_hps_mix, co_neg_HP, co_pos_HP){
  if(val_hps_mix == 0 & co_neg_HP > 0 & co_pos_HP > 0) e[e < max(e[e < 0])] <- 0
  if(val_hps_mix == 0 & co_neg_HP > 0 & co_pos_HP > 0) e[e < 0] <- e[e < 0]/length(e[e < 0])
  e
}
C.NAcc_hetero(e=c(.1, -.2, 0, -.2), val_hps_mix=0, co_neg_HP=1, co_pos_HP=2)
[1]  0.1 -0.1  0.0 -0.1
```

Comment: @ Erik Kornet and @Jilber Urbina Thank you! To store the new value of e: e <- C.NAcc_hetero(e, val_hps_mix, co_neg_HP, co_pos_HP)

Answer (score 1):

You can do so by making `val_hps_mix`, `co_neg_HP` and `co_pos_HP` inputs in your function, like so:

```
e <- c(.1, -.2, 0, -.2)
C.NAcc_hetero <- function(val_hps_mix, co_neg_HP, co_pos_HP){
  if(val_hps_mix == 0 & co_neg_HP > 0 & co_pos_HP > 0) e[e < max(e[e < 0])] <- 0
  if(val_hps_mix == 0 & co_neg_HP > 0 & co_pos_HP > 0) e[e < 0] <- e[e < 0]/length(e[e < 0])
  return(e)
}
```

Then run the function with these inputs:

```
> C.NAcc_hetero(0, 1, 2)
[1]  0.1 -0.1  0.0 -0.1
```

With this structure, the output of `C.NAcc_hetero` will change depending on the values of `val_hps_mix`, `co_neg_HP`, and `co_pos_HP`